# Kinect: How to draw bones with PNG picture instead of DrawLine?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, kinect, system.drawing

Kinect: How to draw bones with PNG picture instead of DrawLine?

[I want the result like this http://www.hotzehwc.com/Resource-Center/Wellness-101/skeleton2.aspx](http://www.hotzehwc.com/Resource-Center/Wellness-101/skeleton2.aspx)

I will get the joints positions from Kinect.

```
JointA.x;
JointA.y;

JointB.x;
JointB.y;
```

The joints positions will change, so the PNG connects between two joints needs to resize and rotate.

Any sample code to make this easier?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you would want to use DrawLine, and other internal draw functions, so that you can scale your bones appropriately.  It's just a lot harder to get them to look right at first.

Using images you would want to cut them up into their individual pieces.  The Kinect has a series of joints which the connecting lines would be the bones.  First check out the SkeletonBasics-WPF example from the SDK Toolkit, supplied by Microsoft -- it will show you have they construct bones between the joints.

Now, you want to cut up your skeleton image in such a way that you have 1 bone per image.  Create an `Image` object in your XAML for each image.  Figure out where the joints belong in your images -- the elbow, for example, will be close to the bottom of the humerus image, but might be a few pixels into the image, and would towards the middle (width wise).

When you get the joint positions from the skeleton, translate the appropriate coordinates from the images into those positions.  It is going to be a lot of math!  You'll get the joints for the given bone and then calculate how to translate the bone image to the correct position and angle.

Comment: Thanks for the replay. After getting the coordinates from Kinect, I'm now having trouble to rotate and resize image. As what you said above, it does need a lot of math. That's why I'm looking for an example to make this easier.